# Neovim Netrw Pop up on start

Tags: lua, neovim, packer, netrw

I am new to lua config and when I setup my auto-pair for brackets everything works except i get a random screen like I'm printing to it with a bunch of function listings. My understanding is that this is downloaded from the github is there any way to fix or disable this. As I said all functionality works as expected.

```
{
  after_regex = <function 1>,
  after_regex_check = <function 1>,
  after_text = <function 2>,
  after_text_check = <function 2>,
  before_regex = <function 3>,
  before_regex_check = <function 3>,
  before_text = <function 4>,
  before_text_check = <function 4>,
  done = <function 5>,
  invert = <function 6>,
  is_bracket_in_quote = <function 7>,
  is_bracket_line = <function 8>,
  is_bracket_line_move = <function 9>,
  is_end_line = <function 10>,
  is_inside_quote = <function 11>,
  move_right = <function 12>,
  none = <function 13>,
  not_add_quote_inside_quote = <function 14>,
  not_after_regex = <function 15>,
  not_after_regex_check = <function 15>,
  not_after_text = <function 16>,
  not_after_text_check = <function 16>,
  not_before_char = <function 17>,
  not_before_regex = <function 18>,
  not_before_regex_check = <function 18>,
  not_before_text = <function 19>,
  not_before_text_check = <function 19>,
  not_filetypes = <function 20>,
-- More --
```

my file structure is

```
nvim
  |_plugin
     |_theme.lua
     |_pair.lua
  |_lua
     |_init.lua
     |packer.lua
     |_remap.lua
     |_set.lua
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER

I figured it out admitly I was being kinda dumb.

- line 10 on the lua setup theres a print(vim.inspect(cond)); that i didn't catch, maybe this will help someone